# Recovering Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

My Ubuntu 11.04 guest on VBox 4.0.10 crashed when I was working. Is there a way to go back to previous working configuration? I have always used the saved state and power off option. I did not take snapshots though. Or is there a way to go back to previous configurations in 
Ubuntu?

Comment: you didn't mention the problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install grub. If installed, you will find recovery option at startup itself.

Comment: I did went through the grub menu and tried the recovery option. Where should I go from there.

Comment: I think the option will automatically begin recovery. Least intervention is needed. It is advisable to save all data using a live CD.